# How to write code to connect a point(x,y) and a circle with shortest distance?

Tags: flutter, dart, geometry

I am making a game and I want to create a code that when I clicked a point it must be connect to the circle being the center of screen, with the shortest distance. It doesn't matter the software language. I only need the algorithm. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the shortest path from a point to a circle be along the line from that point to the circle's origin?

Comment: Can the clicked point be inside the circle?

Comment: Yes jamesdlin, it is, but i can't write the code and make the math. I will click and and it connect to the circle with the line by shortest path and clicked point must be outside of the circle.

Comment: you need two `Offset` points: `center` (circle's center) and `click` (clicked position) then you do: `final delta = click - center` and finally your point is `center + Offset.fromDirection(delta.direction, radius)`

Answer (score 1):

1. When user taps, detect the point of the tap (xtap, ytap)
2. Detect the origin of the circle (xc, yc)
3. The shortest distance between the two would be `sqrt( (xtap - xc)^2 + (ytap - yc)^2) - circle's radius`. We minus circle's radius because you need the distance from the circumference and not the center of the circle.

Comment: It is worth to add calculation of point, not just distance.

Comment: @MBo didn't get what you mean

Comment: You have shown how to find distance, blue segment length. But author really needs coordinates of point where this segment meets the circle: `to connect a point(x,y) and a circle` (look at pskink comment)